# MYSQL join, return first matching row only from where join condition using OR

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm having a problem with a particular MySQL query.

I have `table1`, and `table2`, `table2` is joined onto `table1`.

Now the problem is that I am joining `table2` to `table1` with a condition that looks like:

```
SELECT
table1.*, table2.*
JOIN table2 ON (     table2.table1_id = table1.id
                 AND (    table2.lang = 'fr'
                       OR table2.lang = 'eu'
                       OR table2.lang = 'default') )
```

I need it to return only **1 row** from `table2`, even though there might exists many `table2` rows for the correct `table1.id`, with many different locales.

I am looking for a way to join only ONE row with a priority of the locales, first check for one where `lang = something`, then if that doesn't manage to join/return anything, then where `lang = somethingelse`, and lastly `lang = default`.

FR, EU can be different for many users, and rows in the database might exist for many different locales.. I need to select the most suitable ones with the correct fallback priority.

I tried doing the query above with a `GROUP BY table2.table1_id`, and it seemed to work, but I realised that if the best matching (first OR) was entered later in the table (higher primary ID) it would return 2nd or default priority as the grouped by row..

Any tips?

Thank you!

---

it still doesn't seem to "know" what t1.id is :(

Here follows my entire query, it goes to show table1 = _product_sku, table2 = _product_sku_data, t1 = ps, t2 = psd

```
SELECT ps.id, psd.description, psd.lang
                    FROM _product_sku ps                                

                    CROSS JOIN
                      ( SELECT lang, title, description
                        FROM _product_sku_data
                        WHERE product_sku_id = ps.id 
                        ORDER BY CASE WHEN lang='$this->profile_language_preference' THEN 0
                                      WHEN lang='$this->browser_language' THEN 1
                                      WHEN lang='default' THEN 2
                                      ELSE 3
                                 END
                        LIMIT 1
                      ) AS psd
```

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:**

This version uses variables to provide some sort of ranking within the available languages. Tables and test-data are not from the original question, but from the query OP provided [as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401922/mysql-join-return-first-matching-row-only-from-where-join-condition-using-or/2402507#2402507).

It produced the expected results when I tried it:

```
SELECT id, description, lang
FROM
(
    SELECT ps.id, psd.description, psd.lang,
          CASE
            WHEN @id != ps.id THEN @rownum := 1 
            ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1
          END AS rank,
          @id := ps.id
    FROM _product_sku ps
    JOIN _product_sku_data psd ON ( psd.product_sku_id = ps.id )
    JOIN ( SELECT @id:=NULL, @rownum:=0 ) x
    ORDER BY id,
             CASE WHEN lang='$this->profile_language_preference' THEN 0
                  WHEN lang='$this->browser_language' THEN 1
                  WHEN lang='default' THEN 2
                  ELSE 3
             END
) x
WHERE rank = 1;
```

---

**Old version** which did not work, since `ps.id` is not known in the `WHERE` clause:

This one should return you the rows of `table1` with the "best matching" row of `table2` by using `LIMIT 1` and ordering languages as defined:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.lang, t2.some_column
FROM table1 t1
CROSS JOIN
  ( SELECT lang, some_column
    FROM table2
    WHERE table1_id = t1.id
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN lang='fr' THEN 0
                  WHEN lang='eu' THEN 1
                  WHEN lang='default' THEN 2
                  ELSE 3
             END
    LIMIT 1
  ) t2
```

Comment: Hi again, it seems to work perfectly for what I need, except for one minor detail:

If i hardcode the line within the cross join that reads: WHERE table1_id = t1.id to table1_id = 1, then it works, if i keep it at:

WHERE table1_id = table1.id, then i get:

Unknown column 'table1.id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Sorry, I messed up some aliases :) Please try again with the edited query.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for helping out!

I receive the same error message still, I posted my exact query in the code below for better formatting:

Comment: @ChristianS: Sorry, you are right. Please try my new query, it worked with my tests.

Comment: It's ALIVE!! (works!) Thank you so much for getting back to me Peter! I'd award "ups" but I'm new here. Not sure how else I can contribute back or say "thanks" in a tangible way.

IMMD!

/ Christian

Comment: ok this works but what about performance ?it might be faster just returning locales you want.